# How to find and replace a regex pattern in Linux?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix, sed

I am trying to find and replace a regex pattern in a script.The existing string will be  is like

```
  Input Sample :  abc,c,efh,hj35,"2,6ag=a193",02_TG,",,,,10,,f,,",gf,g,f,,"1720a5",Thgf"18,dhg;_,2,53",0,hg,cj,cj
  Expected Output :  abc,c,efh,hj35,"-",02_TG,"-",gf,g,f,,"-",Thgf"-",0,hg,cj,cj
```

and my replacement String like "-".The code that i have tried is

```
sed -e 's/".*"/"-"/g filename
```

But it's not working!

Comment: do you want `sed  's/,/-/g'` this ?

Comment: What is your expected output? Only `,` needs to be changed to `-`?

Comment: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: @PrudhviPrasanth `*` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: There are no double quotes in the example input, so the regex you have will never match.

Comment: Ok let me put it this way .I want any thing like "1,asd,34,^%$,4" should be replaced with "-" @Inian

Comment: @Biffen can u help me understand how  *  works in here?And also please  suggest me other approach for my problem?

Comment: @PrudhviPrasanth Read *any* regex tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using perl:

```
perl -api -e 's/"[^"]*"/"-"/g' filename
```

Comment: @Toto Thank you .Working.@k-five Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `*` asterisk when you want to match only one single **character** because it is greedy and match as many as it can.

So you simply need `s/,/-/` and that's it.

But if you want to keep anything **before** and **after** that you have, then you can store them in **match-group** parentheses and then back-reference them, like this:

`s/(.*?),(.*?)/\1-\2/`
*or in some search engine*
`s/(.*?),(.*?)/$1-$2/`

---

**NOTE**
The non-greedy `(.*?)` is not supported by most sed implementations. You can switch to Perl which supports it

---

For you **update**
**intput**
`abc,c,efh,hj35,"2,6ag=a193",02_TG,",,,,10,,f,,",gf,g,f,,"1720a5",Thgf"18,dhg;_,2,53",0,hg,cj,cj`

`perl -pe 's/".*?"/"-"/g' your-file`

**output**
`abc,c,efh,hj35,"-",02_TG,"-",gf,g,f,,"-",Thgf"-",0,hg,cj,cj`

[prove](https://regex101.com/r/zZ18UX/1)

Comment: The non-greedy `(.*?)` is not supported by most `sed` implementations.  You can switch to Perl which supports it, but this is still not completely robust e.g. for CSV data with commas inside quotes.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks. Yes you are right. The question has not specific purpose so I wrote in general. Then if the question asked about `"` and etc. then my answer would be the different answer.

Comment: @k-five  May be I have miscommunicated  myself .apologies for that.But i have to match all the characters in between double quotes.Thank You.

Comment: @PrudhviPrasanth Please update your question so that I can figure out what you need. If **my answer** is not useful for you, then tell me and I will delete it. thanks

Comment: @k-five Thanks for trying to help.I have updated the question with  the sample input and Expected output .Can u help??

Comment: @PrudhviPrasanth take a look